# ubuntu 12.10 .htaccess still not working

Tags: ubuntu, .htaccess

I have just installed the Ubuntu 12.10 and I am getting some errors.. I have install the apache2 - ok. But when I am using the .htaccess file in my webfolders I am still getting error 403 forbidden. I rewrite the /etc/apache2/sites-available/default where I edit the AllowOverride None to All and restart the service apache2... But it is still does not work.. I used google, but no solutions found... Is there an error in Ubuntu 12.10 or what? Thanks for replies

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what your problem is but 403s are often caused by filesystem permissions. Check the filesystem permissions for the .htaccess file and the path to it and ensure that the `www-data` user has at least `read` access to the file and `r-x` access to the directories at some level.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do that? How can I check the permissions for thaccess? I add www-data for var/www...many thanks

Comment: @JonáASabína: `ls -l .htaccess` ?

Comment: and what are the right permission for this file?

Comment: When I run following: sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
the htaccess works, and it is not giving me error 403..but now, i have no permissions to add, edit or show the files in /var/www...what to do next?

Comment: @JonáASabína: Spending some time learning how filesystem permissions and ownership works or getting someone to do it for you would be good at this point.

Comment: after I added to all var/www files atributes 777 all work fine...